# RabbitMq REST HTTP : Send integer values in JSON payload

Tags: json, rest, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

[data types of headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M0Xt.png)I am trying to send a message directly to Exchange using the REST endpoint:

```
/api/exchanges/vhost/name/publish
```

The sample payload I am using is:

```json
{ 
  "properties": {
    "timestamp": 1536959503,
    "message_id": "100",
    "correlation_id": " ",
    "priority": 0,
    "delivery_mode": 2,
    "headers": {
      "counter": 0,
      "content-type": "application/xml",
      "correlation-id": " ",
      "message-id": 100,
      "message-type": "message1",
      "status": "P"
    },
    "content_type": "application/xml"
  },
  "routing_key": "p.ee.pp.rr",
  "payload": "sample",
  "payload_encoding": "string"
}
```

In this, the only numerical values in the headers are `message-id` and `counter`.

When I receive the message from the queue into a headers map of type `<String, Object>`, the data type for the numerical values is `Long`.

My code casts `message-id` to `long` and `counter` to `Integer`. I get a class cast exception when doing the latter.

I am interested in knowing:

1. Who is assigning the data type to the numerical values as `Long`? At which stage does it get assigned (in the flow of REST endpoint to the Queue)
2. is `Long` the default type when reading data from JSON?

Comment: I see `message_id` and later `message-id` inside of `header`. Is this mis-match in names causing a problem?

Comment: No....the message gets published successfully...Using debug, i tried to look at the contents of the header. The numerical values have the type Long and other data is of the type String. I am curious to know who is setting the numerical values to Long by default. and if there is any way i can change it.

Comment: Must be the default for integer-like types, so you don't overflow at 256 or whatever. Does replacing `100` with `int(100)` work? Or if you want float, change to `100.0`, or `"100"` for string.